# How build docker image from multiple custom containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have configured `MySQL` + `phpMyAdmin` + `prestashop` containers.
I would like to build a unique image with my own custom containers.

How can I do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you ceated docker files for each one? Have you started the base container images and configured them manually? Can you clarify what you mean with "unique image with my own custom containers"

Comment: I have pull mysql, phpmyadmin and prestashop.
I have link phpmyadmin to mysql 
I have link prestashop to mysql 
I would like build an image from my costum prestashop + phpmyadmin + mysql.
ultimately when I install my custom image I would like an automatic install of this environment. you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). Docker compose will automatically start the images that you have and you can also [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) these images automatically inside docker-compose.

If you have done some manual changes to the containers running, you can commit the container and the changes to a new image using

```
docker commit <mysqlcontainer> mysql-custom-image
```

And then in the compose file, you can just reference those commits.

```
...
image: mysql-custom-image
```

Answer (score 0):

A container is made from a Dockerfile
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

If you want to build your custom container, you should create one and make it as you want it to be!

Here's a tutorial: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/